# How do I add or delete attributes on the 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user page?

Tags: django

How do I add or delete attributes on the 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user page?

I don't know how to add or remove properties from an existing page

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['emp_no', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'hire_date'] 

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Nothing changes

Comment: please fix formatting

Comment: use from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin  , CustomAdmin(admin.UserAdmin) , admin.site.register(User, CustomAdmin)

Answer (score 1):

try this code to changes the django admin auth user fields display

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['emp_no', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'hire_date'] 

admin.site.register(User, CustomAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to change the admin page name (to be more specific) and unregister group if you don't need it (yet) :

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin


admin.site.site_header = 'Your administration name'


class CustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['emp_no', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'hire_date'] 

admin.site.register(User, CustomAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```